# nexus 3 with proxy npm repository

Tags: npm, nexus3

I use nexus 3 (affected all versions from 3.2 to 3.13.0_01) with proxy npm repository.
Sometimes when I build my Angular project I get error like that:

```
[ERROR] npm ERR! node v6.11.2
[ERROR] npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
[ERROR] npm ERR! code ETARGET
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] npm ERR! notarget No compatible version found: ci-info@^1.3.0
[ERROR] npm ERR! notarget Valid install targets:
[ERROR] npm ERR! notarget 1.1.3, 1.1.2, 1.1.1, 1.1.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.0
[ERROR] npm ERR! notarget 
[ERROR] npm ERR! notarget This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
[ERROR] npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
[ERROR] npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
[ERROR] npm ERR! notarget 
[ERROR] npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of 'is-ci'
[ERROR] npm ERR! notarget
```

I found that is-ci depend on npm that released 21 hour ago.

After day or two problem go away without my involve.
My repo does not have negative cache.
Why does it happen?

After reboot problem solved.
Also I noticed message: "System Requirement: max file descriptors [4096] likely too low, increase to at least [65536]."

Nexus run under user "nexus":

```
nexus$ ulimit -Sn
65536
nexus$ ulimit -Hn
65536
```

Why it message appeare?

Answer (score 1):

Try invalidating cache in your repository.

You can find more info here: https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/configuration/repository-management#RepositoryManagement-ManagingRepositoriesandRepositoryGroups

Here's the fragment on cache invalidation:

> **Invalidate cache**
>
> The Invalidate cache button invalidates the caches for this repository. The exact behavior depends on the repository type:
>
> **Proxy repositories**
>
> Invalidating the cache on a proxy repository clears the proxy cache such that any items cached as available will be checked again for any changes the next time they are requested. This also clears the negative cache for the proxy repository such that any items that were not found within the defined cache period will be checked again the next time they are requested.
>
> **Repository groups**
>
> Invalidating the cache of a repository group, clears the group cache such that any items fetched and held in the group cache, such as Maven metadata, will be cleared. This action also invalidates the caches of any proxy and group repositories that are members of this group.

Comment: When posting links as answer, make sure to include a minimal description of the content linked, else your question might be flagged as `not an answer`. Check [this meta thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251006/flagging-link-only-answers) for more infos